# relative url for images saved in post number folders - Rails carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, relative-url

I would like to save my rails images in folders corresponding to the post number an url like this:

`www.domain.com/posts/21/pictures/1.jpg`

the uploader is setup correctly but I can only access the pictures with the exact url and not with a relative path. When, on a show post view `www.domain.com/posts/21`, I use a relative path such as:

```
src='pictures/1.jpg'
```

the image points to:

```
www.domain.com/posts/pictures/1.jpg
```

how can I make sure the base url includes the post number?

Comment: Can you post the view code here...and also the routes.rb file, where the posts resource has been defined...

Comment: I feel you can make use of rails route helpers... post_picture_path(@post, @picture)